# Read the first row from a stored procedure's resultset

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am trying to read just the first row from `xp_readerrorlog` extended stored procedure in a PowerShell script.

Unfortunately, [`ExecuteReader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms199426.aspx) method reads all the records that `xp_readerrorlog` stored procedure returns and sometimes that's a few million rows or a few minutes.

I tried to google it and found out that using DAO one could read data as it returned by the SQL Server but DAO is deprecated and I don't want to go this route.

[`BeginExecuteReader()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a674khd.aspx) doesn't seem to help either as there is no indication if any data has been returned yet until execution is completed which equals `ExecuteReader()`.
Is there any other way to get just a few first rows/pages when working with large recordset?

I understand that I can create a temporary table, dump data into it and `SELECT TOP 1` from it but this will introduce some extra I/O and this is not a solution I am looking for.

Comment: How about [archiving](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrissk/archive/2011/01/05/how-to-archive-your-sql-errorlogs-into-a-table.aspx) your error log and cycling it periodically? Then `sp/xp_readerrorlog` should be more manageable.

Comment: This is one of the workarounds for this particular stored procedure. I might employ this approach if there is no other solution. But it would be nice to find out if what I asked is possible in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with .Net 4.5 `SqlCommand` class has `ExecuteReaderAsync()` method and `SqlDataReader` class has `ReadAsync()` method. It is possible to start processing data as soon as SQL Server starts sending it to the client using these new methods.

Unfortunately, there is no await operator in PowerShell so the code isn't looking as pretty as in C#.

```
$sqlInstance = 'SqlServerName';

$con = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection;
$con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$($sqlInstance);Integrated Security=SSPI;Asynchronous Processing=true;";
$con.Open();

$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLCommand;
$cmd.Connection = $con;

$cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure;
$cmd.CommandText = 'xp_readerrorlog';

# add parameters
$cmd.Parameters.Add('p1', [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int, 1) | out-null;
$cmd.Parameters['p1'].Value = 1;
$cmd.Parameters.Add('p2', [System.Data.SqlDbType]::Int, 1) | out-null;
$cmd.Parameters['p2'].Value = 1;

$cmd.Prepare();

$task = $cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

# wait for first rows
While ( $task.IsCompleted -ne $true ) {
    Start-Sleep -m 10;
}

# PowerShell does not have await operator so a SqlDataReader object can be retrieved this way
$reader = $task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

# read first row
$reader.ReadAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult() | out-null;

$reader['LogDate'];

$cmd.Cancel(); # cancel execution, there is no need to wait for the whole recordset to be transfered to the client

$con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a small misconception about the the [Execute methods work on a ServerConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection_methods.aspx).  They do not have an impact on how stored procedures run.  Even if you used [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.executescalar.aspx) (Executes a Transact-SQL statement and returns the first column of the first row as a value type.) then entire stored procedure would run on the server, then only the first value would be returned.

Your only two options which would improve performance are to create a new procedure that returns the row you want (Sql Performance improvement and Network utilization improvement) or use a temp table to return a single row from the stored procedure (Only a Network utilization improvement).

There are no built in methods on ServerConnection to do what you want in the .Net Framework.

Comment: I didn't try to use **SET ROWCOUNT** for
`INSERT INTO <temptable>
EXEC xp_readerrorlog ...`
but it actually works. It doesn't work when you execute a stored procedure directly.
This is the code I'm going to use. Thanks!

    CREATE TABLE #errorlog (
     [LogDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
     [ProcessInfo] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
     [Text] [text] NOT NULL
    )
    
    SET ROWCOUNT 1
    
    INSERT INTO #errorlog
    EXEC xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'desc'
    
    SELECT * FROM #errorlog
    
    DROP TABLE #errorlog

Comment: Create your own answer with your comment, and accept it as the answer to your question.

Comment: I just tested the code above on a large error log and the execution time was ~2 minutes. That means it actually processes the full recordset and therefore adds some extra load on the server.